# Bazel changes filename of .so, making it un-importable

Tags: python, bazel

I'm using bazel to build a simple python script with

```
py_binary(
   name = "test",
   srcs = ["test.py"],
   data = ["bpy.so"],
   python_version = 'PY3',
)
```

As seen, I'm hoping to be able to import `bpy`, a library I built according to https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu.

I was able to locate it after `bazel build`, but its name is no longer `bpy.so`, but `bpy__py_binary_resource_test__h6PPJs.so`. So now when I tried to import it, I get

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initbpy__py_binary_resource_test__h6PPJs)
```

**My Questions**

(1) Is `data = ["bpy.so"]` the correct way to make sure I can import `bpy` on a remote machine after `blaze build`? I always feel weird to use the keyword `data` for a lib...

(2) If this is the correct way, how do I import it after the build, since the filename has changed and the `init` function inside will no longer be reachable (as told by the error message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, I was able to solve this problem by *not* `bazel build`'ing it into a `.par`.